# What is `tagname` in l3build's `update_tag`?

Tags: tag, l3build

When I write my custom `update_tag` function after the `l3build` fig 11 example of the documentation, `tagname` is nil. What is its expected value and how to configure it ?

Comment: `tagname` is the tag name that you pass to `l3build` when you run `l3build tag`. If I were to run `l3build tagname v0.9` today, `tagname` would be `v0.9` and `tagdate` `2020-01-07`.

Comment: If you write your own `function update_tag(file, content, tagname, tagdate)` you just need to make sure it accepts the arguments in that order. The arguments will be passed to it automatically when you run `l3build tag` and the function is invoked.

Comment: the name and intended use come from tagging a release in git, but you can use it for anything